# One Drive buisness files and folders in root document not visible

Tags: onedrive

In One Drive business UI, files and folders in root document are not visible. But I could retrieve items from root folder through API.

UI shows error as "This item might not exists or no longer available"

Comment: Hi Sonia. Which OneDrive for Business UI are you using? The website, one of the mobile apps, or something else? Are you finding that the UI shows your OneDrive to be empty while the API shows items? Or is it just that the UI isn't showing some items but the API does? Are the items you see in the API files that you created or know about?

Comment: Hi, I am using website UI. UI  doesn't show the items and API shows items. This is been happened just two days ago. previously I could see the items in UI.

Comment: Thanks Sonia. Does the UI show any other items, or is it completely empty? Does it have folders?

Comment: Hi, It is completely empty..